# How can I make Django use the correct current time for my system locale?

Tags: python, django, datetime

From Python interpreter in the Gnome terminal on Ubuntu, I enter and get the following:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print now
2011-03-24 12:27:32.527229
```

With Django, the output to the web browser is an hour behind:

> It is now 2011-03-24 11:27:38.864572.

The Django code (running on the same Ubuntu laptop) is below.

From views.py:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
import datetime
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

And then from urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from myapp.views import current_datetime
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^current_datetime/$', current_datetime),
)
```

I am using the python-django package from the Ubuntu 10.04 repository (version 1.1.1-2ubuntu1.3).

Any ideas why the output differs on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TIME_ZONE` setting in your project is incorrect.

Comment: Doh, I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing it out for me, it works fine now.